# How retrieve json with array on an array on it?

Tags: jquery, json

Problem is I can see already the value of my json through firebug but the problem is appending it to my table I try to change my json_encode from echo `json_encode(array('red'=>$red, 'blue'=>$blue));` to `json_encode($blue);` to see if my ajax really works then the `json_encode($blue);` and I change my `toAppend += '<tr><td>'+data.red[i]['warrior_name']+'</td><td>Name</td><td>'+data.blue[i]['warrior_name']+'</td></tr>';` to `toAppend += '<tr><td>'+data[i]['warrior_name']+'</td></tr>';` then it displays perfectly in my table, but only the blue array and I want both blue and red array. So I want to know what is wrong or I have missing something?

Here's my PHP code:

```
   //get blue_team attributes
$blue = array();

$blue_result = $db->dataWarrior($battle_id,$blue_name);

foreach($blue_result as $warrior){
    $blue[] = $warrior;
}

//get red_team attributes
$red = array();

$red_result = $db->dataWarrior($battle_id,$red_name);

foreach($red_result as $warrior){
    $red[] = $warrior;
}

    echo json_encode(array('red'=>$red, 'blue'=>$blue));
```

Here's my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "battle_review.php",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "json",
                data: { 
                    bname: blue_name,
                    btype: blue_type,
                    rname: red_name,
                    rtype: red_type },
                success: function(data){
                    var toAppend = '';
                    if(typeof data === "object"){
                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            toAppend += '<tbody>';
                            toAppend += '<tr><td>'+data.red[i]['warrior_name']+'</td><td>Name</td><td>'+data.blue[i]['warrior_name']+'</td></tr>';

                            toAppend += '</tbody>';
                        }
                        $("#battledata").append(toAppend);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your output is pretty bad for a proper iteration over it. However, assuming `red` and `blue` always have the same element count you can do thi:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "battle_review.php",
    type: "POST", // uppercase
    dataType: "json", // uppercase T
    data: {
        bname: blue_name,
        btype: blue_type,
        rname: red_name,
        rtype: red_type
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var toAppend = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < data.red.length; i++) {
            toAppend += '<tbody>';
            toAppend += '<tr><td>' + data.red[i].warrior_name. + '</td><td>Name</td><td>' + data.blue[i].warrior_name + '</td></tr>';

            toAppend += '</tbody>';
        }
        $("#battledata").append(toAppend);
    }
});
```

An array like this would be cleaner:

```
[{"red": ..., "blue": ...},
 {"red": ..., "blue": ...},
]
```

Then you could simply iterate over it and access the `red` and `blue` properties of the elements:

```
$.each(data, function(i, row) {
    // row.red
    // row.blue
});
```

Comment: how do I know if its from my blue or red array?

Comment: thanks it works! you said Its pretty bad any suggestions to improve it? if it is ok with you . :)